# Get COL width in pixels (from percentage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit

I have this COL element in a table:

```
<col width="15%"><col>
```

When instructing jQuery to get the width of that `col`, i.e. `$(thatCol).width()`, I will get `15` instead of the calculated pixel value. I need this to manage table column widths and cannot rely on `th`/`td`.

Should I convert to pixel values myself (widthOftableInPixels/colPercentage) or is this a bug in the `width()` method or did I just miss something? Or, maybe there is a plugin that manages table column widths by `col` elements (and can properly handle dynamically adding/removing columns)?

The code should run in WebKit based browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `css()`.Try this:

```
$(thatCol).css('width');
```

Answer (score 0):

`.width()` method gets "...the current computed width" of the element that is used on. jQuery width documentation: http://api.jquery.com/width/, so the return value from `$(thatCol).width()` is in pixels, not percent. Thing is, your current col width could be 15 `pixels`, while you thinking it is in `percent`.